# Why isn't ThreadPoolExecutor able to run this function? It works as a loop

Tags: python, multithreading, function, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
from urllib import request

img_urls = [
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516117172878-fd2c41f4a759',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532009324734-20a7a5813719',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524429656589-6633a470097c',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530224264768-7ff8c1789d79',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564135624576-c5c88640f235',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541698444083-023c97d3f4b6',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522364723953-452d3431c267',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513938709626-033611b8cc03',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507143550189-fed454f93097',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493976040374-85c8e12f0c0e',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504198453319-5ce911bafcde',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530122037265-a5f1f91d3b99',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516972810927-80185027ca84',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550439062-609e1531270e',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549692520-acc6669e2f0c'
]
count=0
tmplist=[]
for img in img_urls:
    tmplist.append(count)
    count+=1

joined = zip(tmplist, img_urls)

def download_image(x, image):
    print(image)
    with open(f'{x}.jpg', 'wb') as img:
        img.write(request.urlopen(image).read())

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(download_image, joined)
```

First time posting here, I am wondering why this doesn't work. To the best of my knowledge the code is going to download each of these images. I've ran the function 'download_image' as a loop and it works fine to download them one at a time. However, when I try to use ThreadPoolExecutor to run this asynchronously it doesn't even give me an error. I'm kind of at a loss debugging this.